# Subroutine within a 'With' statement

Tags: vba, excel

Consider the following illustrative example

```
Private Sub drawBorders(listOfBorders)
    For Each Item In listOfBorders
        With .Borders(Item)
            .LineStyle = xlContinious
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next Item
End Sub


Sub main()
    Dim TopBottom() as Variant
    Dim myRange As Range
    TopBottom = Array(xlEdgeTop, xlEdgeBottom)
    myRange = Range("A1")

    With myRange
        .value = a
        Call DrawBorders(topBottom)
    End With
End Sub
```

I have a sequence of `With` statements where some of the code is pretty repeating.

I get an error at the `DrawBorders` sub :

> Invalid or unqualified reference

Is it possible to import the reference from the `With` statement into the `Sub`?

Comment: Is `myRange` a public variable? That is filled elsewhere? Because there is nothing referring to it in the code you posted. Futher more, you should specify the type of the argument in your `DrawBorders` as the error you get is because of this `With .Borders(Item)` which hasn't any object to be referenced to. My guess is that you wanted to pass the reference inside of your call and that is why you need to pass an object, because the `With` won't follow when you call a function or sub!

Comment: Sorry, the declaration of `myRange` fell out when I did an edit. It's supposed to be there, yes. 
You have understood my problem correctly. Is there a way to push the reference to the `Call` procedure?

Comment: You won't be able to pass a `With Object` reference inside of an argument, but you can pass the Object directly if you type your arguments properly! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always specify the type of the argument in your Sub or Function.

The error in `DrawBorders`you get is because of this `With .Borders(Item)` which hasn't any object to be referenced to (no `With Object` before).

My guess is that you wanted to pass the reference inside of your call and that is why you need to pass an object, because the `With` from the main code won't follow when you call a function or sub!

Here is my proposition for your code :

```
Private Sub DrawBorders(ListOfBorders As Variant, RangeToFormat As Range)
    For Each Item In ListOfBorders
        With RangeToFormat.Borders(Item)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next Item
End Sub

Sub main()
    Dim TopBottom() As Variant, _
        Ws As Worksheet, _
        MyRange As Range

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set MyRange = Ws.Range("A1:J10")
    MyRange.Value = A

    TopBottom = Array(xlEdgeTop, xlEdgeBottom)

    With Ws
        Call DrawBorders(TopBottom, .Range("A1:J10"))
    End With
    '----Or
    'Call DrawBorders(TopBottom, MyRange)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
Private Sub DrawBorders(listOfBorders() as Variant, r As Range)
    For Each Item In listOfBorders
        With r.Borders(Item)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next Item
End Sub

Dim TopBottom() As Variant
Dim myRange As Range
TopBottom = Array(xlEdgeTop, xlEdgeBottom)
myRange = Range("A1")

With myRange
  .Value = a
End With

Call DrawBorders(TopBottom, myRange)
```